# changing the permissions of a file after its publishing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have a document library that contains:

> Title,Publish Status

Publish Status is drop-down menu field with two status: `Draft or Publish`

Once the field is set to publish,the permission of the file must change.
The user can't edit or delete
how would I procede?

I am using SharePoint 2013

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Okay, what is your question ?

Comment: how to procede, I am new to sharepoint :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should instead use the **versioning settings** features rather than a choice column. There you have many chances to find what you need (content approval etc.).